# How to import google services plugin into library？

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, variant

I have two application variants: google and china. But china variant doesn't need firebase. If I import google services plugin into the application, then china apk includes it. This apk throws

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError-"Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' 
(declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in ".
```

So, I want to let google services plugin to library A. In app, I can use googleCompile A . But now the plugin only uses the client object that matches the package name (for the current build type). How can I import google services plugin to library?

Comment: Did you try to have a build.gradle file for each variant?

Comment: how can do that？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getGradle().getTaskGraph().each {
    it.addTaskExecutionListener(new TaskExecutionListener() {
        @Override
        void beforeExecute(Task task) {
            if (task.name.contains("GoogleServices")) {
                Field field =  task.class.getField("packageName")
                field.setAccessible(true)
                field.set(task,"com.aaa.bbb.ccc")
            }
        }

        @Override
        void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState state) {

        }
    })

}
```